# Flutter SvgPicture in TextField not adapting color

Tags: flutter, svg

When I set the `TextField.prefixIcon` property to an `Icon(Icons.example)` widget, the color of the icon automatically adapts according to the state of the TextField (enabled, focussed, ...).
Now, I got an Icon Pack with svg files that I want to use within the TextField. I am using [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) to show them like that:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Password",
    prefixIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
      AppIcons.lock,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Now, how can I achieve the automatic color adaption with SvgPicture?

Answer (score 0):

you need to resolve it manually :

```
  FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  bool _enabled = true;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return TextFormField(
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      enabled: _enabled,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: "password"
      ).copyWith(
        prefixIcon: SvgPicture.asset(AppIcons.lock, color: _resolveColor())
      ),
    );
  }

  Color _resolveColor(){
    if (_focusNode.hasFocus){
      return Colors.yellow;
    }
    if(!_enabled){
      return Colors.white;
    }
    if (!_form.valid){
      return Colors.red;
    }
    return Colors.grey;
  }
```